# Is the concatenation of two one-way functions a one-way function when each function takes different inputs?

Tags: one-way-function

Similar to [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/51123/is-the-concatenation-of-two-one-way-functions-a-one-way-function?rq=1), but having two seperate inputs for each length preserving one way function $f$ and $g$, i.e. $h: \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace^{2\kappa} \to \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace^{2\kappa}, h(x) = f(x_1)||g(x_2)$ where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are two $\kappa$ bit split halves of x.

I think $h$ will be one way, but am not sure on the appropriate reduction to demonstrate this.

I think I don't need to show that the probability of an attacker decrypting this being negligible in polynomial time but rather reduce to problems of one-wayness of $f$ and $g$ and knowing that they are one way should demonstrate that in fact $h$ is one way

Comment: This seems like a good candidate for a proof by contradiction. Assume you were able to invert $h(x_1 || x_2)$ (with non-negligible probability). Are you then able to leverage this ability to invert either $f(x_1)$ or $g(x_2)$ (with non-negligible probability)?